# How to copy a file from Isolated Storage to Phone Storage WP8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I was creating an application which creates a text file and storing that file in Isolated Storage.

```
        if (!myFile.FileExists(sFile))
        {
            IsolatedStorageFileStream dataFile = myFile.CreateFile(sFile);
            dataFile.Close();
        }
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(sFile, FileMode.Open, myFile));
        string rawData = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();

        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(sFile, FileMode.Append, myFile));
        string[] hello = new string[] { "av", "vd", "dbg" };
        for (int i = 0; i < hello.Length; i++)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(hello[i]);
        }
        sw.Close();
```

I need to move that file stored in Isolated Storage to the Phone Storage. How to achieve this in Windows Phone 8 application?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can write it directly into local storage. [This might help.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj681698(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_FilesandfoldersAPIoverview)